# how to define custom login page using angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS and ui-router with Spring MVC. 
I'm trying to put security for my application using Spring Security. I'm actually having issue with the login page (but the login is working correctly with the basic login page provided)

The problem is i can't access my login page since it's mapped by UI-Router and Spring Security don't understand /login the same way as Angular.

Here is a part of my Security Config :

```
http.
        httpBasic()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
         /* .loginPage("/app/#/login") not working */
         /* .loginPage("/app/login") not working */
            .successHandler(authSuccess)
            .failureHandler(authFailure)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/app/js/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/app/img/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/app/lib/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/app/partials/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/app/index.html").permitAll()         
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Actually, i'm getting the login alert because of .anyRequest().authenticated() and the login works fine with it, but i really need my custom login page.

I'm using UI-Router so my index.html contains a ui-view and my login.html is located in /app/partials/login.html

Any idea how to access my correct login page through Spring Security loginPage() ?

Comment: did you try to authorize your urls as antMatchers("/app/login").permitAll()

Comment: I succeeded login in with my custom login page. The issue was in my controller, i was posting on the wrong URL /app/login instead of /login. Now i have a different problem about redirect to correct login page if wrong/unauthorized URL instead of the login alert form but i hope i will figure it out. 
I'll post a complete answer once all problems are solved.